# Дано действительное число x. Вычислить с точностью 10^(-6)

Tags: python, циклы, ряды

[image: На фото представлен пример, который мне нужно решить через Python.]
Дано действительно число x. Точность 10^-6. Решить через циклы. Вот что я сделал. Я рассуждал так: Если модуль числа с элементом k в этой сумме больше заданной точности, то оно удовлетворяет условию.

```
import math
x = float(input("Введите заданное число x: "))
k = 1
s = 0
p = math.pow(10, -6)
q = (math.pow(-1, k) * math.pow(x, k)) / k
v = math.fabs(q)
while (v >= p):
    s += q
    k += 1
    q = (math.pow(-1, k) * math.pow(x, k)) / k
    v = math.fabs(q)
    print(v)
print(s)
```

Comment: Я надеюсь, число x по модулю меньше единицы? Показывайте, что у вас есть из кода

Comment: `- log (x+1)` просто вывести. если `|x| < 1`

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, код должен быть в нём.

Comment: Про Область допустимых значений не было ничего сказано

Comment: скорее всего, я ошибся немного. Мне нужно каким-то образом отделить наверное дробную часть и сравнивать с заданной точностью. Или нет?

Comment: Ну наверное стоит и принять, что ОДЗ меньше единицы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pow здесь использовать ни к чему, следующая степень получается просто домножением на X. Перемена знака - тем более, умножение на -1

Результат можно проверить по формуле, приведённой pavel `-math.log(x+1)`

```
x = float(input("Введите заданное число x в пределах -1..1: "))
k = 1
q = -x
v = q
s = 0
eps = 1e-6
while (abs(v) > eps):
    #print(v)
    s += v
    k += 1
    q *= -x
    v = q / k
print(s)
```

или даже так:

```
x = float(input("Введите заданное число x в пределах -1..1: "))
k = 1
q = -x
s = 0
eps = 1e-6
while (abs(q) > eps):
    s += q
    q *= -x*k/(k+1)
    k += 1

import math
print(s, -math.log(x+1))
```

Comment: А каким образом вообще проверяется точность? Ну то есть как понять, что эта сумма вычислена с точностью 10^-6? Тем более, когда питон выдает тебе не точные данные, а приближенные.( вот к примеру 10.01 - 0.1= 0.10000000012312313 и т.д).

Comment: При x в указанных пределах ряд сходится, каждое следующее слагаемое по модулю меньше предыдущего, и под точностью можно понимать то, что два последовательно вычисленных значения s отличаются не более, чем на eps.

Comment: При положительном X ряд будет знакопеременный, и разность s с истинным значением на графике выглядит как затухающая пила https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lKkU.png, она останавливается, когда разность зуба вверх и зуба вниз отличаются менее, чем на eps, и отличие от точного значения не более eps/2. При отрицательном X график просто стремится к истинному значению, разность между соседними значениями тоже не превышает отличие от истинного.

Comment: Так то всё-таки точность довольно приблизительная, но кроме как по члену ряда как ещё останавливаться. На `-0.9` например разница с формулой получается `-8.7e-06`, то есть больше искомой.